# What's the equivalent of <Location> in .htaccess?

Tags: httpd, apache-2.2

I'm setting up Trac, and want to password protect the login page, as suggested [here.](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracCgi#AddingAuthentication)  I'm on a shared hosting setup, so I can't modify the httpd.conf, I have to use .htacces.  How do I restrict just the login page without restricting other pages?  The Trac docs suggest:

```
<Location "/trac/login">
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Trac"
  AuthUserFile /somewhere/trac.htpasswd
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

But the Location tag is only for httpd.conf, it doesn't work in .htaccess.  How can I get the same effect?  There's no "login" directory to put a .htaccess file into, it needs to go into the main trac directory.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a guess, but can you place that in a .htaccess file, minus the `<Location>` and `</Location>` tags, inside the /trac/login directory?

Also, be sure to have your `htpasswd` file outside the document root (commonly public_html) otherwise it can be downloaded and cracked.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, dreamhost has [a page on this very problem.](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Troubleshoot_Trac_One-Click_Install#Solution_2)  Short answer: there's no good way to do it through apache configuration, so use the [TracAccountManager plugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AccountManagerPlugin) instead.

Answer (score -2):

In apache 2.4 this can be done by modifying the allow override directive in root httpd.conf or specifically for your host.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html

```
<Directory "/www/htdocs">
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Location "/trac/login">
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Trac"
  AuthUserFile /somewhere/trac.htpasswd
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Comment: The question is probably being asked because the asker has no access to httpd.conf.